# embed iphone contact on page click link

Tags: iphone, html

my question is analogous to the "mailto:email@email.com" type of link but is more specifically:

if a phone number exists on a page and is viewed by a user on an iphone (phone number will appear as link), is there a way for that link to automatically (upon user clicking) ask the user if they want to add that number to the contact, and then auto fill certain details?

this seems a bit too amorphous to be obviously possible, but you never know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Phone numbers will be recognized by Mobile Safari automatically, and be "forced" to be seen as telephone numbers by doing something like this:

```
<a href="tel:5551212">555-1212</a>
```

But you can't control the phone's behavior when the user taps the link. (Cool feature idea though. :) )

Answer (score 0):

It think it's not necessary to use a tel: as a href protocol prefix. I am not sure if something like this validates or is somehow standard. There is also a skype href hack: href="skype:asdasdasd".

#### Alternative Solution

iOs also detects telephone numbers in text automagically. They just need the right format. See also here for formats: http://hjacob.com/blog/2009/07/making-a-phone-number-clickable-for-iphone-users/